# Need help to add help button and minimize to system Tray button in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I wanted to know how to add the help button and minimize to system tray button in Power builder window title bar. Does any one know it. kindly help me. Help with sample code are highly appreciated. Am having PB10.5 and SQLSERVER 2008.

Thanks and regards
Pushparaj

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add your app to the system tray.
http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_icontray.html

I don't know how to put a button on the title bar.

Comment: I have already included that code in my app. I am looking for the code to add button on the Window Title Bar. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You could uncheck the Titlebar property on your window and design your own fake title bar. The following code in the mousedown (pbm_lbuttondown) event will support dragging the window around the screen: CONSTANT uint WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 161
CONSTANT uint HTCAPTION = 2

Post(Handle(this), WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, Long(xpos, ypos))