# how to create objects at powerbuilder Properties Bar

Tags: powerbuilder

Am using power builder 10.5. Am having a data window as a base object. And doing some base coding in it. I am having some Boolean instance variables in it. When i use this user object at base window , on the properties bar i can see the check box for the Boolean Variables which i declared on base user object. like wise for string a text box and integer data types. My requirement is to have an radio button and combo box in that bar. Do any one knows about this. For this how i want to code in the base object , so the developer can choose either one option, that will reflect in the base code.

Thanks and regards ~
Pushparaj V.(India)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a possibility: it consists in the undocumented property "descriptor" that one can add to a userobject property to tell how a property should be displayed / manipulated.

You can have a description in the (French) [PBadonf thread about descriptors](http://pbadonf.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?id=991). It is my only information source, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: thanks a lot @Seki. You did a nice job. I have seen your codings. And i understand it. I want to learn more about this, shall i know where to download the help document of the "PB 7.0
Documentation for Advanced Users". So that i can gain more relative knowledge about this.

Comment: one more guidance i need Sebastien, i didnt find the exact answer for my previous question. [Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111757/need-help-to-add-help-button-and-minimize-to-system-tray-button-in-powerbuilder). Do you have any idea about this.

Comment: @Raj: Unfortunately, I have never found the PB7 documentation mentioned in the post and the newsgroup relative post. This documentation has vanished, perhaps that an ancient programmer that is using PB since release 7 or before could provide it some day?

Comment: @Raj: Roland Smith was correct when he told you for your former question about how to add an icon in the tray bar. For the part relative to add a button in the title bar, I unsure it is possible with PB as it will need to interact with the native Windows API to draw a button outside of the client rectangle in the windows decorations. I have never done it before, and if it involves callbacks it won't be possible directly with bare PB. Maybe easier from a PBNI extension?

Comment: I have implementer your code on my sample application. I found some difficulties to use those. I list out those for your better understanding.
1. First i Have written the code in instance Variables. It has Created new tab in properties bar As well as the duplicate of the variables are present at General Properties Bar. But i don't that variable to be present on General Tab.
(see next reply for continues)

Comment: 2.So i placed the code in Object's Edit Source at global Type. Now the above mentioned Problem is solved. But i cannot access that on that Base object Itself. It says Undefined Variable. And when i return back to Object Edit Source that code is not Present on there. 
help me to solve this Problem. I want the Object Properties to be displayed on separate Tab, and that should not repeat at General Tab.

Comment: Public boolean  ib_ancrage_haut descriptor "pb_format"="DataType=boolean~tGroup=Additional Properties~tDivider=User Object Properties~tLabel=Check" = true
Public string is_sizemode descriptor "pb_format"="Group=Additional Properties~tStyle=SingleChoice~tLabel=SizeMode~tItems=clip!|stretch!"
Public string is_borderstyle descriptor "pb_format"="Group=Additional Properties~tLabel=Sorting Type~tDivider=User Object Properties~tStyle=SingleChoice~tItems=Enable Sort|Disable Sort"

Comment: Public long il_pictwidth descriptor "pb_format"="Group=Additional Properties~tStyle=SingleChoice~tLabel=PictureWidth~tItems=(Default)|16|32~tValues=0|16|32"
Public Alignment ie_alignment descriptor "pb_format"="Group=Additional Properties~tStyle=SingleChoice~tLabel=Alignment~tItems=Center!|Left!|Right!~tImages=106|16|2|0|1"
Public grGraphType ie_graphtype descriptor "pb_format"="Group=Additional Properties~tStyle=Enum~tLabel=GraphType~tSystemType=grGraphType~tImages=104|16"

Comment: Public FillPattern ie_fill descriptor "pb_format"="Group=Additional Properties~tStyle=Enum~tSystemtype=FillPattern~tLabel=FillPattern~tImages=103|24"
Public LineStyle ie_linestyle descriptor "pb_format"="Group=Additional Properties~tStyle=Enum~tSystemtype=LineStyle~tLabel=LineStyle~tImages=102|24|0|1|2|3|4|-1"
-------------------

Comment: I have used Standard Visual Datawindow User Object. 
First i place on Instance Variable Place. Some of the Variables are repeated at General Tab.
So i placed on Objects Edit Source Place. But i cannot access those declared variables on that object itself. 
I want you to clearly understand my problem. That's why i gave this much explanation. Expecting Your Reply .... @seki Am Sorry if this long explanations irritates you.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any control on how the properties are presented.